# How to add NFC-based loyalty card to Google Pay?

Tags: android, nfc, google-pay

The Google Pay API documentation [says](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/overview/basics/about-google-pay-api-for-passes) that it is possible to add NFC-based loyalty cards to Google Pay.

But I [see no details](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/implementing-the-api/save-to-google-pay) how to provide the API with the data needed for NFC communications.

How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you need to apply for early access [here](https://support.google.com/pay/merchants/answer/7394344). How to use NFC reader terminals to read Smart Tap data is under NDA.

Here is a video of reading Apple and Google Pay passes: 
[PassNinja Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/Bjr7-5DD_4h/?hl=en&taken-by=passninja)

Disclosure: I work for [Flomio](http://flomio.com/). The company behind [PassNinja](http://passninja.com/).

Comment: Thank you. Could you please clarify how it works - can it emulate existing cards (Mifare Classic 1k, for ex.) or does it use its own standard (the standard itself is under NDA, as I got from your message)?